# Oracle query - get latest record if multiple records are returned

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c

I am using a stored procedure inside a package that connects to a DB using db link and periodically pulls data to update local DB. It does so by pulling data into a "staging" table, do some processing and update local table.

It worked fine until I ran into an issue where I ended up with multiple/duplicate records having different `CREATEDON` timestamps but same `ITEM_ID` and `EVENTCODE`.

This is a watered down version of the query:

```
LVSPICKSQL:='INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE (A, B, ITEM_ID, EVENTCODE, CREATEDON)
SELECT (A, B, ITEM_ID, EVENTCODE, CREATEDON) FROM SOME.DBLINK@BLAH WHERE STATUS=1 AND PCIKEDON IS NULL) WHERE ROWNUM <= 200;

EXECUTE IMMIDIATE LVSPICKSQL;
```

I thought combination of `ITEM_ID` and `EVENTCODE` were unique; found out that is not the case.

Now, I need to modify this query so that if there are multiple records for same `ITEM_ID` and `EVENTCODE`, I pick the latest one (latest `CREATEDON`).

Comment: Doesn't `WHERE ROWNUM <= 200` have a meaning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for that:

```sql
select A, B, ITEM_ID, EVENTCODE, CREATEDON from 
    (select A, B, ITEM_ID, EVENTCODE, CREATEDON, 
                   row_number() over(partition by ITEM_ID, EVENTCODE 
                        order by CREATEDON desc) rn from SOME.DBLINK@BLAH
     where STATUS=1 and PCIKEDON is null
    )
where rn = 1;
```